# LateInitializationError: Local 'newTaskTitle' has not been initialized. (It doesn't add new task if i minimize the keyboard?)

Tags: string, flutter, dart

So I run into some problems that I can't find a solution to on google.

When I try to add a new task to my app, it all works but when I write something and swipe on my phone to go back/close the keyboard, and then press add it doesn't do anything and shows me this error code. If I tap on main screen to go back and start process all over again and click add with keyboard opened it adds it normally. How can I solve it do it will add the task when user closes the keyboard?

Here is my code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late String newTaskTitle;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: mybackgroundcColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Add Question",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: myColor),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: myColor),
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: myColor),
                ),
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: myColor),
                ),
              ),
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (newText) {
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                "Add",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: mybackgroundcColor,
                ),
              ),
              color: myColor,
              onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                    .addTask(newTaskTitle);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
      void addTask(String newTaskTitle) {
        final task = Task(name: newTaskTitle);
        _tasks.add(task);
        notifyListeners();
      }
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit of error message

```
The following LateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
LateInitializationError: Field 'newTaskTitle' has not been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      AddTaskScreen.newTaskTitle (package:todoey_flutter/screens/add_task_screen.dart)
#1      AddTaskScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:todoey_flutter/screens/add_task_screen.dart:59:30)
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
```

Answer (score 1):

When the keyboard appears or closes, it will cause the widget to rebuild. In your case, you have declared the variable `newTaskTitle` inside the build method. When you press the *ADD* button after closing the keyword, its causes the whole build function to rebuild, `newTaskTitle` too. Thus you try to save unassign string variable to `onPressed` function.

To fix this, Declare the variable `late String newTaskTitle;` outside of build function.

Comment: I think the issue have been fixed, at first it seem like it didn't work but later not sure how it just disappeared. Thanks!